# SQL GROUPING values from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, concatenation

I'm having an issue with a large (100,000s record) SQL database.

Here's the basic structure:

**bookings** - bookingcode, bookingdate

**payments** - paycode, bookingcode, paydate, payamount

**pupilrecords** - prcode, bookingcode, lessonscode, coursecode

**lessons** - lessoncode, coursecode, resortcode

**resorts** - resortcode, resortname

**Notes**
The pupil record can contain either a lessoncode or a coursecode but not both.
A record in the lessons table may or may not contain a coursecode, if it does, that links to the pupil record, if it doesn't, the pupil record is linked by the lessoncode.

I need to run a report that shows what payments are received on a particular date. Here's the SQL code I run at the moment:

```
SELECT payments.payamount,
  (COALESCE(resorts1.resortname, '') + COALESCE(resorts2.resortname, '')) AS rname
FROM   payments
LEFT JOIN   pupilbookings
       ON  payments.bookingcode = pupilbookings.bookingcode
LEFT JOIN   lessons  AS lessons1
       ON  pupilbookings.lessonscode = lessons1.lessonscode
LEFT JOIN   resorts  AS resorts1
       ON  lessons1.resortcode = resorts1.resortcode
LEFT JOIN   lessons  AS lessons2
       ON  pupilbookings.coursecode = lessons2.coursecode
LEFT JOIN   resorts  AS resorts2
       ON  lessons2.resortcode = resorts2.resortcode
WHERE  paydate = ' & date_here & '
GROUP BY payamount,
         resorts1.resortname,
         resorts2.resortname
ORDER BY rname
```

All runs well as long as a booking hasn't got two pupilrecords - one with a lessoncode, the other a coursecode that point to separate "lessons" records but ultimately one "resorts" record". If that happens, the payment is listed twice.

How can I group the resortname (generated as rname) so that the record will only appear once even if it's linked from the original payment in two ways.

I hope that all makes sense!

Comment: If there are two payment records, do you want the sum?  If you just want one of the records, which one do you want?

Comment: Just a remark: You are not using any aggregate function, so you don't have to use GROUP BY either. Use DISTINCT instead, if you really want to select distinct values, which I would consider strange actually. I agree with Dan Bracuk: Think about what you want to select.

Comment: i think pupilrecords  table design is bad.
- It should be prcode, bookingcode, code, CodeType int
where CodeType=lessonscode,1 and coursecode,2
and code will be either lessoncode then type=1 or coursecode and type=2

Comment: There is a marker in the lessons for whether it is a course or lesson but kept it out so as not to confuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not positive I follow what you're after, but if you don't want multiple records, you can eliminate the 2nd set of joins and just expand your `JOIN` criteria:

```
SELECT payments.payamount
      ,COALESCE(resorts1.resortname, '') AS rname  
FROM payments  
LEFT JOIN pupilbookings 
      ON payments.bookingcode= pupilbookings.bookingcode
LEFT JOIN lessons AS lessons1 
      ON   pupilbookings.lessonscode = lessons1.lessonscode
        OR pupilbookings.coursecode = lessons1.coursecode                       
LEFT JOIN resorts AS resorts1 
      ON lessons1.resortcode = resorts1.resortcode
WHERE paydate = ' & date_here & '  
GROUP BY payamount, resorts1.resortname
ORDER BY rname
```

Comment: This appears to have done the trick.  Thanks so much for your help, really appreciated.